# Recursive call that confuses me

Tags: c, recursion

I have the following function

```
int vowels(char *str)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (! str[0])
        return count;
    if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", str[0]))
        count ++;
    return count + vowels(&str[1]);
}
```

That performs counting all the vowels that appear in a string, what confuses me is the recursive call **vowels(&str[1])** do not understand why on every call goes to the next character, without doing this **str++**. They can help me understand this? please.

Comment: looks like a recursion exercise

Comment: str should be const btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within each function call that is declared like

```
int vowels(char *str);
```

though I would declare it like

```
size_t vowels( const char *str );
```

expression

```
&str[1]
```

is equivalent to

```
str + 1
```

or

```
++str
```

However you may not use

```
str++
```

because the value of the expression is the address stored in `str` before the increment.

As for me I would define the function the following way

```
size_t vowels( const char *s )
{
    return *s ? ( strchr( "aeiouAEIOU", *s ) != NULL ) + vowels( s + 1 ) : 0;
}
```

Comment: which it is the difference between str++ and str + 1

Comment: By the way very elegant the way you expose

Comment: @Tony If you have for example int x = 1; then the value of epression x + 1 is 2 while the value of expression x++ is 1.

Answer (score 2):

`vowels(&str[1])` calls `vowels` using the address 1 byte after `&str[0]`, the start of `str` in memory. Because `str` is a `char *`, this means it uses the string minus its first character.

Note that you would not want to do `str++` or `&str++`, as those would attempt to modify `str` itself, rather than just *using* part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

There's is no reason to do `str++` if the address to the next element is taken with `&str[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Well strings are stored in memory. What this is doing is passing the address of a char to the char pointer of the function `str`. So `&str[1]` is simply the address of the next char of the array (it just jumps to the next byte).